# (Error) : The function queryRecords must return an array of records

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to print the count in the Calculated database but getting below error

Able to print the search result in console logs properly

Records push Error -Executing query for datasource Aggregation: (Error) : The function queryRecords must return an array of records, but the array contained an element that was not a record.

```js
function getStatisticsBypening_() {
  var searchVal = app.models.Company.newQuery().run();
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < searchVal.length; ++i) {
     var recordType = searchVal[i].Status;
    if (recordType === 'Pending')
      count++;
  }
  console.log(count);
   var records = [];
   var record = app.models.Aggregation.newRecord();
   record.Count = count;
   records.push(count);
   return record;
}
```

Error

[image]

Comment: `records.push(count);` should be `records.push(record);`

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi 
No Dear tried getting the same error 
(Error) : The function queryRecords must return an array of records, but the return value was not an array.

Comment: Sorry one more change `return record;` should be `return records;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are not returning an array in response,

Here's the updated code

```
//Server Side
function getStatisticsBypening_() {
  var searchVal = app.models.Company.newQuery().run();
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < searchVal.length; ++i) {
     var recordType = searchVal[i].Status;
    if (recordType === 'Pending')
      count++;
  }
  console.log(count);
   var records = [];
   var record = app.models.Aggregation.newRecord();
   record.Count = count;
   records.push(record);
   return records;
}
```